# Why does a collision detection in a cryptographic hash function make finding other collisions easier?

Tags: security, hash, cryptography, digest-authentication

From Wikipedia, I read:

> *Joux[3]  noted that 2-collisions lead to n-collisions: if it is feasible to find two messages with the same MD5 hash, it is effectively no more difficult to find as many messages as the attacker desires with identical MD5 hashes.*

But why is this so? I can't imagine why? The algorithms are open right, people can read the maths which generates the hashes, which is the digest machinery. So if we know one collision why does it help find new ones?

Is it just making small iterations to both of the first collision messages and then monitoring their changes to remap them?

Comment: Good question, but unfortunately not programming related.

Comment: finding the other collisions will require programming...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a property of all hash functions, but a weakness of the [Merkle–Damgård construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction) (which MD5 and SHA-1 are based on), known as *length extension*. The weakness involves the fact that you can "resume" the hash calculation with specially-selected appended data. For full details of how this is used to generate arbitrarily many collisions, see:

- [*Multicollisions in Iterated Hash Functions. Application to Cascaded Constructions*](http://www.cs.pdx.edu/~teshrim/spring06/papers/general-attacks/multi-joux.pdf) (Antoine Joux)

For a related attack based on this idea, see:

- [Understanding hash length extension attacks](http://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/programming/HashLengthExtAttack)
- [Flickr's API Signature Forgery Vulnerability](http://vnhacker.blogspot.com/2009/09/flickrs-api-signature-forgery.html)

Comment: While length-extensions are related, this is a distinct weakness. In particular a hash function can have this property without being vulnerable to length-extensions. For example when you find a same-length collision in Skein-512-512, that implies a state collision, and thus allows multi-collisions. For other hash functions an output collision doesn't imply a state-collision, but a state-collision still implies multi-collisions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key here is the word "feasible". In crypto-land, feasible means "reasonable amount of time compared to the value of whatever it is I'm trying to break", or maybe "less time that it would take using brute-force" depending on how you look at things.

So, if I can find 1 collision feasibly then I can find n collisions feasibly because `n*small` is still small.

There will still be *some* n where `n*small > value of breakage`.

Would this apply to other hash functions? I believe so, but I could be wrong.

Let the flaming commence.

Comment: If you know one MD5 collision (of same length messages) finding more related collisions is extremely cheap/much cheaper than finding that first collision. Just append the same string to both of them, and it's still a collision.